# TestNG @Parameters fails on java but passes on xml files ! How can I fix this issue?

Tags: parameters, testng, optional-parameters

My test case is passed when I run it on with XML file but when I run it on java code on eclipse it fails. and getting error says that

```
"Parameter &apos;URL&apos; is required by @Test on method WebloginCarLoan but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in          c://.... "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:** Through the xml you are specifying the parameter in the xml, if you run directly through the plugin, the parameter cannot be found since it is in xml.

**Solution** You need to set your xml as a template xml for this to work.  Go to Project->Properties->TestNg.  Set your xml as the template xml.  Then run your case, the parameter will be picked from the xml.